# Cordova release built APK cannot be installed on Android

Tags: android, cordova, apk

Command "Cordova build android" produces an apk file named app-debug.apk that I can install on my device (Samsung A3 with Android v8.0)

Command "Cordova build android --release" produces an apk file named app-release-unsigned.apk that won't install on same device ("App not installed").

I must also add that I am not trying to publish that apk on a Playstore. I also tried to sign the APK but it doesn't change the outcome.

What should be the essential differences between these 2 files? What could be the reasons causing the release version to fail?

Here is the content of config.xml located in the Cordova project folder:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="eu.jrc.treechecker" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>TreeChecker</name>
    <description>
        A mobile application 
    </description>
    <author email="*******" href="********">
        Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" /> 
    <access origin="*" />
    <icon src="www/img/ic_canhemon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="24" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dbcopy" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^3.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Here is the content of platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="eu.jrc.treechecker" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

EDIT : Here is what I would use for a build.json:

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "appname-mobileapps.keystore",
            "storePassword": "***",
            "alias": "appname-mobileapps",
            "password" : "***",
            "keystoreType": ""
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "appname-mobileapps.keystore",
            "storePassword": "***",
            "alias": "appname-mobileapps",
            "password" : "***",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a build.json containing your signatures for siging the APK?

Comment: To my understanding build.json is only necessary for a signed apk but an apk doesn't need to be signed to be installed on a device. Anyway I edited my question with the build.json that I used when trying to sign the release apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug build and release build are two different things. The first one is meant for developers whereas the second one is for your users. In order to produce a release build in Cordova, you can either use the `Cordova CLI` or use `Android Studio`.

**Cordova CLI**

In order to make a release build using the CLI, you will need to run `cordova build --release` along with a set of arguments. Running the command without configs would not give a successful build. These arguments are necessary to sign your app for play store. Further, these configs can be supplied either in the cli or by having a `build.json` config file. Cordova docs on [Signing an App](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#signing-an-app) gives you more insight into this.

**Android Studio**

This way is a relatively easy way to make a release build. All you need to do here is to load your app onto the android studio, and then follow the screen instructions on how to  [Generate Signed apk](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk) to obtain a release version. It will ask you to create a key file, which is required for future releases.

Comment: To my understanding the apk doesn't need to be signed if I don't want to publish it on play store. In my case I just want to distribute to a handful of users through a shared drive. By the way I also tried all what you mentioned but to no avail. What is the essential difference between cordova build --release and --debug which would explain why one could be installed but the other not?

Comment: @Pierric release build cannot be debugged.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the answer above but I post here what I did step by step, also because the method proposed on cordova website did not work for me.

```
# build apk
cordova build android --release

# sign apk (I used keytool to create mykeystore)
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <mykeystore> <PATH-TO-app-release-unsigned.apk> <appname-alias>

# align apk
zipalign -v 4 <PATH-TO-app-release-unsigned.apk> <final-apk-name>
```

Comment: In case someone else is wondering what or where all those tools are: `keytool` should be in the bin folder of your java/jdk/jre installation and `zipalign` is part of the android sdk build tools.

In my case for example:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin` and 
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3`

Comment: My problem was that I used the outdated apksigner instead of jarsigner. I had been stuck in this for days and you were a life saver. I don't know who downvoted this post.